# Проверка по рег. выражению

Tags: javascript

Проверка формы на английские символы, если введены только английские то true, если что то кроме английских то false. Как исправить что бы правильно работало

"gggg" > true

"рррр" > false

"арff" > true

```
var a = document.getElementById('form-n');

a.onkeyup = function (e) {
    var d = a.value;

    var r = /[a-z]/gi;
     console.log(d)
    if (!r.test(d)) {
        console.log("false")
    } else {
        console.log("true")
    }
}
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, очевидно: почему для `pppp` выдает _false_

Comment: @АлексейШиманский исправил вопрос

Comment: вот после исправления, я не понял в чем вопрос :-)

Comment: .обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это все потому, что регулярное выражение проверяет только английские буквы, а в строке находится что-то иное, в данном случае русские `р`, которые не походят под данное выражение.

Почему это не работает для строки `арff`, в которой вторая `р` - русская?

Потому что данное выражение *ищет* хотя бы один символ в строке удовлетворяющий выражению.

Для того чтобы показать, что *кроме* этих символов в строке ничего не должно быть, нужно изменить выражение следующим образом

```
/^[a-z]*$/i
```

указав, что проверяется *вся* строка

```js
["gggg", "рррр", "арff"].forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el, /^[a-z]*$/i.test(el));
});
```